# Problems using reflection with java-mongo driver

Tags: java, reflection, mongodb-java, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying this code http://ideone.com/gymUrP

```
Object obj2 = coll.getClass().getMethod("find").invoke(coll, new Object[]{});
```

is working with an empty second argument (matching find() method) but I didn't manage to make the other methods work, like the one with this signature ([Docs](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find%28com.mongodb.DBObject%29))

The exception returned is always *`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: wrong number of arguments*

#### edit

Thanks to answers, this is close to what I'll need: (a bit heavy though)

```
Object[] args = new Object[]{new BasicDBObject("a", 2)};
Class[] types = new Class[args.length];
for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
    types[i] = (Class) args[i].getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0];

Object obj = coll.getClass().getMethod("find", types).invoke(coll, args);
System.out.println(obj);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) I'd say you missed the `parameterTypes`. I'd assume it to be:

```
Object obj2 = coll.getClass().getMethod("find", new Class[]{})
                             .invoke(coll, new Object[]{});
```

or

```
Object obj2 = coll.getClass().getMethod("find",null)
                             .invoke(coll, new Object[]{});
```

Look at [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getmethod.htm) as well.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, it helped me more to find what I need

Answer (score 2):

It should work with this call, passing a `DBOject` parameter and getting the method expecting this parameter:

```
DBOject dbo = ...
Object obj2 = coll.getClass().getMethod("find", DBOject.class).invoke(coll, dbo);
```

(I assume `coll` is a `DBCollection` object.)

Comment: This would be another method, however, basically it should work as well. But I think it should be `new Class[]{ DBOject.class };` instead of `DBOject.class`.

Comment: Object obj2 = coll.getClass().getMethod("find", DBObject.class).invoke(coll, new Object[]{new BasicDBObject("a", 2)}); works but this isn't easy to use, (it was meant to be really dynamic and use other possible signatures easily)

Comment: `Class.getMethod` takes a `Class<?>...` vararg, no need to explcitly create the array. I also simplified the `invoke` call.

Comment: ctrl, the Reflection API does not allow such a dynamic call. At best you can guess the arguments in your code or iterate over all class methods and invoke the first whose arguments match your needs.